# Crystal Report font spacing changes

Tags: crystal-reports, fonts, spacing, crystal-reports-xi

We have some reports that have a large text field.  I've set the font to ariel 9.  In Crystal Designer, it takes up the space I've given it.  When I move it to our Business Objects sever, it moves each letter closer to each other, and each line closer to each other, making it seem like there is extra space to the right and bottom of the field, with more space at the bottom the more lines in the field.

I changed my report on the server from DHTML viewer to ActiveX viewer, and that fixed it -- as long as I ran it from the server.  As soon as it is run from the web page that calls it, however, it's back all scrunched up.

How do I control the spacing on a font, both in designing and in running the report?

Comment: Are you viewing the report (in the two viewers) on the same machine where you built it?  What fonts are listed in the DHTML viewer?

Comment: I am viewing the report on the same machine, Win7.  I don't know what fonts are listed in the DHTML viewer, but I'll try to find out.